# I can’t autocomplete my Go code even after installing vim-gocode

Tags: vim, go

#### My setup

I already installed gocode with the command `go get github.com/nsf/gocode`.

I use Pathogen to manage my Vim plugins. I installed vim-gocode with `git clone git@github.com:Blackrush/vim-gocode.git`.

#### What I’m seeing

The `:Fmt` command works ok, but I can’t autocomplete my golang code. It reports an error like in this image:

[image: E117: Unknown function: go#complete#Complete]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi.  I haven't used vim-gocode.  I have however used https://github.com/fatih/vim-go with great success.  The only obvious thing that I could think of is $GOPATH/bin isn't on your path?  What OS/version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you have [YCM](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) or [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) installed. You need some additional binaries to get all features. Following on the vim-go repo tells you how to install them.

> All necessary binaries should be installed (such as gocode, godef, goimports, etc.). You can easily install them with the included :GoInstallBinaries command, by running command in your vim.

Comment: if GoInstallBinaries fails, try GoUpdateBinaries, that fixes it for us.